# Cloth not sewing together all the way

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

Why are some sections not sewing together all the way? I've tried adding more geometry but it still doesn't give me a clean sew.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is apparently because the collision margin around the body is too large / the shirt is too small. Tightening the collision margin may fix the problem, but at the cost of stability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The garment is physically too small to fit around your mesh, allowing for the ‘Outer’ collision margin you have set on your collider Cloth and Soft Body collision settings.

‘Apply Scale’ on each of your meshes (good practice for *any* simulation), reduce collision ‘Outer’ and/or increase the size of your garment.